# Why does `watch` make `ls /tmp` list contents of $HOME?

Tags: shell, ls, watch

I'm trying to watch number of files in my `/tmp/` directory. For this I thought this command would work:

```
watch sh -c 'ls /tmp/|wc -l'
```

But it appears to work as if `ls` had no arguments. Namely, I'm in `~`, and I get number of files there instead of `/tmp/`. I found a workaround, which seems to work:

```
watch sh -c 'ls\ /tmp/|wc -l'
```

But why do I need to escape the space between `ls` and `/tmp/`? How is the command transformed by `watch` so that `ls` output is feeded to `wc`, but `/tmp/` is not passed as argument to `ls`?

Comment: `watch "sh -c 'ls /tmp | wc -l'"` doing this command should get the desired affect. This isn't watches fault, try `sh -c ls /tmp` and you'll get your home directory (but I have no idea why...)

Comment: Not an answer but you're using `watch` incorrectly .The command that you pass to `watch` is in turn fed by `watch` to `sh -c`, so you're in effect doing `sh -c` twice.

Comment: If you are curious you can also have a look at the [source](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/watch.c#L647).

Comment: @JacobMinshall, the why is straightforward: The `/tmp` is an argument to `sh`, in that case, not an argument to `ls`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The difference may be seen via `strace`:

```
$ strace -ff -o bq watch sh -c 'ls\ /tmp/|wc -l'
^C
$ strace -ff -o nobq watch sh -c 'ls /tmp/|wc -l'
^C
$ grep exec bq* | grep sh
bq.29218:execve("/usr/bin/watch", ["watch", "sh", "-c", "ls\\ /tmp/|wc -l"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
bq.29219:execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "sh -c ls\\ /tmp/|wc -l"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
bq.29220:execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "ls /tmp/"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
$ grep exec nobq* | grep sh
nobq.29227:execve("/usr/bin/watch", ["watch", "sh", "-c", "ls /tmp/|wc -l"], [/* 54 vars */]) = 0
nobq.29228:execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "sh -c ls /tmp/|wc -l"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
nobq.29229:execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "ls", "/tmp/"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
```

In the backquote case, `ls /tmp` is passed as a single argument to the `-c` to `sh`, which runs as expected. Without this backquote, the command is instead word split when `watch` runs `sh` which in turn runs the supplied `sh`, so that only `ls` is passed as the argument to `-c`, meaning that the sub-sub`sh` will only run a bare `ls` command, and lists the contents of the current working directory.

So, why the complication of `sh -c ...`? Why not simply run `watch 'ls /tmp|wc -l'` ?

Comment: Oh indeed, didn't think of trying to `strace` it.

Comment: Actually, \` is backquote (or back-tick).  This question is about \, which is backslash.

Comment: @Ruslan: I posted this comment *on this answer* because it is a comment *on this answer*.  thrig says "In the **backquote** case, `ls /tmp` is ..." and "Without this **backquote**, the command is ...", and uses `bq` and `nobq` as filenames, when all the while referring to the ***backslash*** in your `ls\ /tmp` command.

Answer (score 8):

There are two main categories of `watch` commands (of the ones that are to run commands periodically, `watch` is not a standard command, there are even systems where `watch` does something completely different like snooping on another tty line on FreeBSD).

One that already passes the concatenation of its arguments with spaces to a shell (it does in effect call `sh -c <concatenation-of-arguments>`) and one that just runs the command specified with the arguments specified without invoking a shell.

You're in the first situation, so you just need:

```
watch 'ls /tmp/|wc -l'
```

When you do:

```
watch sh -c 'ls /tmp/|wc -l'
```

your `watch` actually runs:

```
sh -c 'sh -c ls /tmp/|wc -l'
```

And `sh -c ls /tmp/` is running the `ls` inline script where `$0` is `/tmp/` (so `ls` is run without arguments and lists the current directory).

Some of the `watch` implementations in the first category (like the one from procps-ng on Linux) accept a `-x` option to make them behave like the `watch` of the second category. So with there, you can do:

```
watch -x sh -c 'ls /tmp/|wc -l'
```